# AndroidSlidingUpPanel with PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sliding, android-tabstrip

When I tried to use [PagerTitleStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) in the main content with [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), the PagerTitleStrip doesnt show up. My structure is:

- SlidingUpPanelLayout

  - LinearLayout

    - PagerTitleStrip
    - ViewPager
  - LinearLayout

    - slideup layout

Answer (score 0):

PagerTitleStrip should be child of View Pager. It goes like below.

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout
    ViewPager
        PagerTitleStrip
    LinearLayout
        slideup layout
```